# Why static methods are bad, apart from tests

Tags: unit-testing, static

Many times I hear "Singleton is a bad practice, static methods are bad practice" all I can see for reason is "hard to test".

But I do think sometimes its really good if an operation can be done without instantiate a class.

EDIT: just because of testing, anyone can find out that "private methods are bad too, they cant be tested" for example

Comment: You cannot stub the class that contains it. Which means that every piece of code that uses that `static` method will have the implementation as-is. Mocking isn't as straightforward as instance methods.

Comment: again tests: mocking, stub. Find a reason which are not related to tests :)

Comment: Your argument towards private methods is irrelevant because unit tests are not supposed to test implementation details, which include private methods, in the first place. Yes, if you don't want to test your code then you could get away with lots of static methods. Do you really want to go that route?

Comment: no, I dont want it, but the way I see it is: those language element has been OK for decades - and then somebody comes, and say "they are bad because of test"

Comment: Singleton is **not** bad practice. There. That's my opinion. I have provided just as many reasons as some unidentified person making statements without context or support.

Answer (score 9):

It is a question about semantics and [expressing intent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intentional_programming).

A static method is not inherently bad, apart from that it is hard to test. The bad part is confusing other programmers by using static methods just to avoid creating new instances.

If the method relates to the **class** itself and not to individual instances (Like a factory method for example), then by all means use a static one. But if the method semantically belongs to an individual instance, then use a non static method.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods are generally frowned upon for much the same reason as global variables, in addition to testing issues:

- Static methods do not relate to a specific class instance so will not always be thread safe.
- Systems with lots of statics methods often do not scale well.
- Confusion due to the mixture between calling static methods of a class and members of an instance of a class can lead to maintenance issues.